# validate html form fields when print button is clicked in context menu

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have a html form in my desktop application using phpdesktop chrome browser. i have a problem validating form fields since this form has no submit button at all because i intended to use this form for printing only so no need to submit any data online or submit button.
i want javascript or php to check this form when user trying to print this form from context menu, simple is that!
i only want javascript or php to make sure no field remains empty before print and all fields must filled with data.
any help will be highly appreciated. thanks

> form.html

```
<form>
                <div class="field1">
                    <input class="varify-field" id="varify-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="80" size="14" onkeyup="updateVerifyname();"><div class="varify-name"></div>
                    <input class="walad-field" id="walad-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="14" onKeyup="updateWaladname();"><div class="walad-name"></div>
                </div><!-- field1 closed here -->
                <div class="field2">
                    <input class="sakan-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="11"><div class="sakan-name"></div>
                    <input class="tehsil-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="7"><div class="tehsil-name"></div>
                    <input class="zila-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="7" placeholder=""><div class="zila-name"></div>
                </div><!-- field2 closed here -->
                <div class="field3">
                    <input class="barmisal-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="11"><div class="barmisal-name"></div>
                    <input class="darja-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="3"><div class="darja-name"></div>
                    <div class="hai"></div>
                </div><!-- field3 closed here -->
                <div class="field4">
                    <h4 class="last-line"></h4>
                </div><!-- field4 closed here -->
                <img  class="darkhwast-dahinda-img" height="33" width="275" src="../images/darkhwast-dahinda-img.png">
                <div class="name-wrap">
                    <input class="name-field" id="name-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="14"><div class="name"></div><div class="name-field-no"></div>
                </div><!-- name-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="disc-maj-wrap">
                    <div class="disc-maj-name"></div>
                </div><!-- disc-maj-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="father-wrap">
                    <input class="father-field" id="father-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="14"><div class="father-name"></div><div class="father-field-no"></div>
                </div><!-- father-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="address-wrap">
                    <input class="address-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="100" size="45"><div class="address-name"></div><div class="address-field-no"></div>
                </div><!-- address-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="marital-status-wrap">
                    <input class="marital-status-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="9"><div class="marital-status-name"></div><div class="marital-status-field-no"></div>
                </div></br><!-- marital-status-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="wife-husband-wrap">
                    <input class="wife-husband-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="8"><div class="wife-husband-name"></div><div class="wife-husband-field-no"></div>
                </div><!-- wife-husband-wrap closed here -->

                <div class="occuption-wrap">
                    <input class="occuption-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="14"><div class="occuption-name"></div><div class="occuption-field-no"></div>
                </div><!-- occuption-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="identity-wrap">
                    <input class="identity-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="10"><div class="identity-name"></div><div class="identity-field-no"></div>
                </div><!-- identity-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="sign-wrap">
                    <input class="sign-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="13"><div class="sign-name"></div><div class="sign-field-no"></div>
                </div><!-- sign-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="birth-wrap">
                    <input class="birth-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="21"><div class="birth-name"></div><div class="birth-field-no"></div>
                </div><!-- birth-wrap closed here -->
                <div class="childs-name-ages-wrap">
                    <h4 class="childs-name-ages"></h4><div class="childs-name-ages-no"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="name-age">
                    <div class="nname"></div>
                    <div class="age"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="empty-name-age1-1">
                    <input class="empty-name-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="15">
                    <input class="empty-age-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="12">
                </div>
                <div class="empty-name-age1-2">
                    <input class="empty-name-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="15">
                    <input class="empty-age-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="12">
                </div>
                <div class="empty-name-age1-3">
                    <input class="empty-name-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="15">
                    <input class="empty-age-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="12">
                </div>
                <div class="empty-name-age1-4">
                    <input class="empty-name-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="15">
                    <input class="empty-age-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="12">
                </div>
                <div class="empty-name-age1-5">
                    <input class="empty-name-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="15">
                    <input class="empty-age-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="12">
                </div>
                <div class="empty-name-age1-6">
                    <input class="empty-name-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="15">
                    <input class="empty-age-field-1" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="12">
                </div>
                <table class="id-card">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="15"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td class="daash" contenteditable='false'>-</td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td class="daash" contenteditable='false'>-</td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="finger-prints">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="15"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="disc-maj-container">
                    <div class="disc-maj-2-wrap">
                        <input class="disc-maj-2-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="7"><div class="disc-maj-2-name"></div>
                    </div><!-- disc-maj-2-wrap closed here -->
                    <div class="date-wrap">
                        <input class="date-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="25"><div class="date-name"></div>
                    </div><!-- date-wrap closed here -->
                    <div class="zila-number-wrap">
                        <input class="zila-number-field" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="40" size="26"><div class="zila-number-name"></div>
                    </div><!-- date-wrap closed here -->

                </div><!-- disc-maj-container closed here -->
                <div class="image-container" style="width:230px;height:275px;">
                    <div class="domicile-pic"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually using javascript it is not possible to cancel the print event. In other words you can not prevent the user from manually triggering the print. You can handle the window `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` events and do your validation, but you can not cancel these events. You can add some style sheet which will inform the user that the form is not valid. To do that you can use this script:

```js
function beforePrint() {
  console.info("Validation before print");
};

function afterPrint() {
  console.log("Called after print");
};

if (window.matchMedia) {
  var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
  mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
      beforePrint();
    } else {
      afterPrint();
    }
  });
}

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
```

Comment: thanks for answer but above script is not working please can you give me a working example along my form.html?

Comment: Yes I can, but could you create a fiddle for your form first? thanks

Comment: ok here is fiddle! **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqeelpld/odthpLc2/)**

Comment: So I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/odthpLc2/1/ In the function `beforePrint` you can do your validation and if the validation fails you can show some `alert` to the user to inform about missing fields. For that I used `isValid` property. Instead of alert you can add some style which will hide or show some parts of your html.

Comment: its working now but not the way i want him? because after fill all the blanks  its still give the error alert strange isn't it? is there any way to exclude some of fields with their classes? because in this form if some ones marital status is unmarried then obviously he or she will not fill childern's names and ages fields! thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it is than all about the validation function. How do you do the validation? Do you use jquery?

Comment: no i don't use any validation. please help me to validate this with jquery because i am new to jquery and never validate form before thanks

Comment: I updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/odthpLc2/3/ I made there validation function `isValid` which will take all input fields, and check if the field is empty. Than it shows the names of all empty fields. When you assign unique name for each input field you can get a nice alert message. It is really simple validation. In the `isValid` function you can check any field you want and how you want.

Comment: Currently all your fields have the same name `fname` so the message is not very clear. But you should change the `name` attributes to have unique names.

Comment: can i exclude some input fields?

Comment: yes you can it is totally up to you just in the foreach cycle skip what you want I do not know which ones you want to validate but the solution is there

Comment: So, did it help your or not?

Comment: first of all thanks for caring!  i can't figure it out how to exclude some of fields? and 2nd is there any other solution of this problem a better one maybe!

Comment: i want to exclude input field with the class **barmisal-field** on line **13** and input fields with classes **empty-name-field-1** and **empty-age-field-1** 0n line **60** to **81** because these fields are optional!

Comment: So just in the code I gave you (in the foreach cycle) check if the current element has one the classes you mentioned, and if it has it then skip this node. Should I write the if statement for you?

Comment: thanks for the fiddle but its doesn't work in php desktop chrome but do work fine in chrome browser! i really don't know whats going on?

Comment: I think the these answers target your original question. If you think so, please mark it as an answer for others. If some script is not working in your special browser it is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Gets all input fields
var allInputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var allInputFieldsLn = allInputFields.length;

// Loops through all inputs to validate they are not empty
var inputIsEmpty = false;
for (var i = 0; i < allInputFieldsLn; i++) {

    if (allInputFields[i].value == "") {
        inputIsEmpty = true;
        return;
    }
}


// Checks if empty input was found
if (inputIsEmpty == true) {
    console.log("An input was not filled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, first of all, you will need to add an `name` attribute to your form tag for access purpose.

Then you have to get every fields from your form and iterate over them to check them as following (plain javascript) and mark if a field is empty with a boolean when encountering an empty input:

```
 function validateForm() {
    var inputArray=document.forms["nameOfYourForm"]
    var hasOneEmpty = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
       if ((inputArray[i].value == null) || (inputArray[i].value === "")) {
          hasOneEmpty = true;
       }
    }
    if (hasOneEmpty === true) {
       // Do something if it has one empty
    } 
}
```